# WPF: Find if mouse cursor is in a control (not necessarily directly over)

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tab control where right clicking on a tab item shows a context menu.
When click on a menu item called "Close" I want to close tab item that the user right clicked on.

Here is a problem.
If I have TabItem1 and TabItem2 and TabItem1 is selected. Then right click on TabItem2 and click "close". At this point, TabItem1 is still selected item but I want to close TabItem2 and i don't know how to get TabItem2.

If I can get if a cursor is in a control (and not directly over b/c it is directly over a TextBlock I added to the tab item header) I would be able to find the control and remove it from Tabcontrol.Items

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to know which tab you right-clicked on, not which one the mouse is over when you select "Close" (especially since the mouse might not be over *either* of the tabs anymore when you click "Close").

Answer (score 0):

Use the ContextMenuOpening event to determine which tab the context menu was opened from, then there is no need to worry about the mouse:

```
<TabControl TabItem.ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="context_menu"  >
            <MenuItem Header="Option 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Option 2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Tab 1" Content="This is Tab 1" ContextMenu="{StaticResource context_menu}" />
    <TabItem x:Name="tab2" Header="Tab 2" Content="This is Tab 2" ContextMenu="{StaticResource context_menu}" />
</TabControl>
```

And the event handler:

```
private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    //get the tab item:
    TabItem bob = e.Source as TabItem;
}
```